# Combining 2 dataframes of different lengths by nearest observed datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently trying to find a way to merge specific rows of `df2` to `df1` based on their datetime indices in a way that avoids lookahead bias so that I can add external features (`df2`) to my main dataset (`df1`) for ML applications. The lengths of the dataframes are different, and the datetime indices aren't increasing at a constant rate. My current thought process is to do this by using nested loops and if statements, but this method would be too slow as the dataframes I am trying to do this on both have over 30000 rows each. Is there a faster way of doing this?

**df1**

```
index                 a   b
2015-06-02 16:00:00   0   5
2015-06-05 16:00:00   1   6
2015-06-06 16:00:00   2   7
2015-06-11 16:00:00   3   8
2015-06-12 16:00:00   4   9
```

**df2**

```
index                 c   d
2015-06-02 9:03:00    10   16
2015-06-02 15:12:00   11   17
2015-06-02 16:07:00   12   18
                ...   ...  ...
2015-06-12 15:29:00   13   19
2015-06-12 16:02:00   14   20
2015-06-12 17:33:00   15   21
```

**df_combined**
(because you can't see the rows at `06-05`, `06-06`, `06-11`, I just have `NaN` as the row values to make it easier to interpret)

```
index                 a   b   c   d
2015-06-02 16:00:00   0   5   11   17   
2015-06-05 16:00:00   1   NaN NaN NaN
2015-06-06 16:00:00   2   NaN NaN NaN
2015-06-11 16:00:00   3   NaN NaN NaN
2015-06-12 16:00:00   4   9   13   19
```

`df_combined.loc[0, ['c', 'd']]` and `df_combined.loc[4, ['c', 'd']]` are `11,17` and `13,19` respectively instead of `12,18` and `14,20` to avoid lookahead bias because in a live scenario, those values haven't been observed yet.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand what exactly you're trying to achieve but you probably want https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you need [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html). assuming your index are ordered in time, it is with the direction backward.

```
print(pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, direction='backward'))
#                      a  b   c   d
# 2015-06-02 16:00:00  0  5  11  17
# 2015-06-05 16:00:00  1  6  12  18
# 2015-06-06 16:00:00  2  7  12  18
# 2015-06-11 16:00:00  3  8  12  18
# 2015-06-12 16:00:00  4  9  13  19
```

Note that the dates `06-05`, `06-06`, `06-11` are not NaN but it is the last values in df2 (for `2015-06-02 16:07:00`) being available before these dates in your given data.

**Note**: if what your dates are actually a column named index and not your index, then do:

```
print(pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='index', direction='backward'))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you!